# Axios authorization request fails in Vue

Tags: asp.net-core, axios, authorization

I'm trying to call an api with authorization header but the options request returns with 500 internal server error.

**EDIT:**

> Other api requests were successful but the ones in need of authorization fail everytime.
>   I tried adding

```js
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('user_token')}`,
```

but nothing changed.

```js
OPTIONS /api/v1/User/GetUserRoles HTTP/1.1
Host: expensesapp.ir
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,authorization
Referer: http://localhost:8080/signin
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
```

**EDIT2:**

```js
const instance = axios.create({
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('user_token')}`,
    },
    baseURL: 'http://expensesapp.ir/api/v1',
    withCredentials: true,
    validateStatus: function (status) {
        return status >= 200 && status < 501
    },
})
```

```js
getUserRoles (personId) {
        return instance.post('/User/GetUserRoles', { personId })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.data.isSuccess) {
                return res.data.data
            }
            throw new Error('An Error has occured.')
        })
}
```

Comment: Your problem is backend, because the HTTP status is 500. Other thing, the header Access-Control-Allow belong to response Header, not request Header.

Comment: are you not forgeting the single quotes around the Authrization key?

Comment: @AntonToshik The IDE deletes the single quotations

Comment: Could you share more code that could reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Rena There you go